# low cardinality index still slows query down

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

using MySQL 5.5 with InnoDB.
have a query like

```
    SELECT
        count(distinct a.thing_id) as new_thing_count,
        sum(b.price) as new_thing_spend
    FROM thing ii
    LEFT OUTER JOIN thing a
        ON a.customer_id = ii.customer_id
        AND a.created_at >= '2013-01-01'
        AND a.created_at <= '2013-03-31'
    JOIN whatsit b
        ON b.whatsit_id = a.original_whatsit_id
    WHERE ii.customer_id = 3
```

where

- `thing` has a cardinality of about 25k, 3.5k of which belong to customer 3
- there are 12 possible `customer_id`s

Now, when I run this query with an index on `customer_id`, it takes about 10 seconds. When I drop the index, it takes .03 seconds.

I can't figure out why this might be. Here's the result of explain without the index:

```
1   SIMPLE  ii  ALL                 24937   Using where
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL                 24937   Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  b   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db.a.original_whatsit_id    1
```

here it is with the index (`thing_customer`)

```
1   SIMPLE  ii  ref thing_customer  thing_customer  4   const   3409    Using index
1   SIMPLE  a   ref thing_customer  thing_customer  4   const   3409    Using where
1   SIMPLE  b   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db.a.original_whatsit_id    1
```

Can someone help me interpret why this index is slowing things down SO much when logically it doesn't seem like it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your DB engine decides to read the index, it reads rows one by one in order. This can lead it to read a row in disk page 2, another in page 4, another in page 1, the next in page 2, etc.

Sometimes, the going back and forth is such that the index is not going help -- on the contrary.

If the DB engine does a poor job at collecting and analyzing statistics on the table while generating the query plan, it might not identify that the index yields completely fragmented disk reads. This is likely what you're experiencing.

Try analyzing the tables to collect new stats:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html

And then retry with and without the index.

Comment: Seems like reasonable advice, but in practice it did nothing to speed up the query... It seems incredibly likely that the data is, in fact, heavily fragmented. Is there nothing to be done in this case?

Comment: well, if you're constantly querying against one field, you could create a clustered index on it so that the table is ordered accordingly. In your case, one on `(customer_id, created_at)` might actually make sense.

Comment: Another thing you could do if your data isn't sensitive, would be to report the bug over at mysql. The planner should know better than use an index when it'll mean reading rows back and forth all over the place. (Postgres, fwiw, does an excellent job at this, if a switch is a possibility.)

Comment: Only one clustered index is allowed per table, and I've got one on thing_id (being the primary key of thing), which is joined against everywhere so I want to keep that one. And yes, there's been talk of switching to Postgres or similar, but it hasn't happened yet. I guess for now I'll just drop the index... Thanks!